# Handling race conditions with Redis Cache

Tags: java, redis, race-condition

I am looking at  a problem, where I have an object that contains a string key, and a counter. Every time the object is accessed the counter is decremented. This brings in the problem of race conditions. To handle this I have coded the following, using the synchronized keyword

```
try {
            option = cartRepository.findById(url);
            Rate rate = option.get();
            synchronized (this) {
                if(rate.getRate() > 0) {
                    rate.decRate(1);
                    allow = true;
                    cartRepository.save(rate);
                } 
            }
        } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
            cartRepository.save(new Rate(url, 5));
            allow = true;
        }
```

I was wondering, if redis itself has functionality that increments or in this case decrements a counter every time you access on that key.
The docs are a tad confusing. it does talk about auto increment on a key. But I am guessing, its not creating a two part key, with the key and counter. But autoincrements a key every time you create and save a new object.

Comment: Can you use [`INCR`](https://redis.io/commands/INCR) and [`DECR`](https://redis.io/commands/decr) redis commands to change counter value? These commands return the counter value after operation is performed. If you have many counters to maintain you can store them in a hashmap and use [`HINCRBY`](https://redis.io/commands/hincrby) command.

Comment: I have looked at the documentation for INCR and DECR, its very confusing. It increments a key that is a number. My keys are all URLS. And I cant find out how to use that Command. I have a very simple set up. My rep extends CrudRepository <Rate, String>. The way I see it, I would have to not use CrudRepository to connect to REDIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to Sergie, this is the working code

```
public boolean isAllowed(String url, String maxRate) {
        logger.info("URL is "+url);
        boolean allow = false;
        ValueOperations<String, String> valueOps = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
        String rate = valueOps.get(url);
        logger.info("RATE "+rate);
        if(rate == null) {
            valueOps.set(url, maxRate, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            allow = true;
        } else {
            valueOps.decrement(url, 1);
            if(Integer.parseInt(rate) > 0) {
                allow = true;
            }
        }
        return allow;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a key to hold the counter and use [`INCR`](https://redis.io/commands/INCR) command to change counter value. This command returns the counter value after operation is performed.

You can use `ValueOperations` in Spring Data Redis to issue this command. Here's sample code:

```java
StringRedisTemplate rt = new StringRedisTemplate(factory);

ValueOperations<String, String> valueOps = rt.opsForValue();

valueOps.set(KEY, "10");
System.out.println(valueOps.get(key));
System.out.println(valueOps.increment(KEY, 1));
System.out.println(valueOps.increment(KEY, 1));
System.out.println(valueOps.increment(KEY, -1));
```

The output will be:

```
10
11
12
11
```

In case you have many counters to maintain you can store them in a `hashmap` and use [`HINCRBY`](https://redis.io/commands/HINCRBY) command. With Spring Data Redis you can use [`HashOperations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/HashOperations.html) to manipulate values in the hash. [See this page](https://stackabuse.com/spring-boot-with-redis-hashoperations-crud-functionality/) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you that is what I am looking for, clean simple and workable.